# Will an I2C device get detected when it is connected to Raspberry Pi when there is no Driver and dts related to it?

Tags: raspberry-pi, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, i2c

I'm in confusion that will an I2C device get detected in raspberry pi even when there
are no device drivers and DTS files related to it.

Will it show up when we use this command

```
ls /dev/i2c-*
```

and are we able to detect its address when I try to probe using

```
 i2cdetect -y bus_number
```

Comment: If the I2C device is not in the device tree, but can be detected by `i2cdetect` then you can access it from userspace using the programs in the `i2c-tools` package or by using the `libi2c` functions.

Comment: if it is not detected, then I need to write dts file right?

Comment: The dts should describe the devices that form part of the system (except for devices on "plug-and-play" buses such as PCI and USB). The i2c-tools programs talk to the I2C buses directly and only care whether I2C addresses are "busy" (claimed by a kernel driver) or "free" (not claimed by a kernel driver).

Comment: @IanAbbott, I2C is non-discoverable bus, and what you suggested is a lottery. In some cases a lottery with broken (burned) hardware.

Answer (score 1):

### In short:

> ... when there are no device drivers and DTS files related to it.
>
> Will it show up when we use this command
>
> `ls /dev/i2c-*`

No. This command will list available I2C buses, not devices.

> and are we able to detect its address when I try to probe using
>
> `i2cdetect -y bus_number`

Maybe. In most cases yes.

---

### A bit more elaborated:

Depending of what kind of I2C device it is, and what you want to do with it, you might still be able to communicate with it.

#### driver - best case

If you have relevant device tree change to describe this I2C device (on what bus it is located, its address, extra signals if needed - like interrupt pin, etc) and associated driver is present (built-in or as a module, check `*_defconfig` options in Linux kernel source) - driver should *probe* device during either boot or manual module loading.

Why best case? If you have a driver you don't have to think about protocols and programming, and, as an example, reading a value from ADC device might be as simple as:

```
root@pi:~# cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_voltage0_raw
291
```

#### i2ctools

Another approach would be to use `i2cget`/`i2cset` tools from `i2ctools` package. No device tree changes needed. With these tools you can talk with any unclaimed I2C device on any enabled I2C bus in device tree.

You'll need to implement communication with I2C device by your own. From security and stability perspective - IMO this is the worst case to go, but is good for hardware debugging and, in some cases, initial bring-up.

Example is [here](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/i2c-tools/i2cset.8.en.html).

Note regarding `i2cdetect` - this command tries to detect devices on particular bus, but gives no warranty. As per man `i2cdetect`:

> As there is no standard I2C detection command, i2cdetect uses arbitrary SMBus commands (namely SMBus quick write and SMBus receive byte) to probe for devices.

Comment: Depends, but strictly speaking it's not possible. I2C is **not** discoverable bus.

Comment: What `SPI` has to do with I2C?

Comment: @0andriy right. I guess I got distracted multiple times while I was writing this. Of course, SPI has nothing to do with I2C.

Comment: `SPI has nothing to do with I2C` - ???  I use mostly I2C, but IMHO it has things in common w/SPI.

Comment: @Seamus Like what? Apart from that is also a serial bus, of course?

Comment: Just offhand, the Python SMB library does SPI and I2C. They have been described by some as [*"interchangeable in some scenarios"*](https://www.arrow.com/en/research-and-events/articles/spi-vs-i2c-protocols-pros-and-cons). But if that upsets you, you're free to ignore it.